# Custom lint rule: How to fix "This annotation is not applicable to target 'expression'"

Tags: android, static-analysis, android-lint

I am writing my first custom [lint](https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/api-guide.html)-detector for android/compose:

"Don't use the standard button, use our specifically styled custom button"

---

The detector itself is working as expected:

[image]

---

Lint suppression however doesn't work as expected: "This annotation is not applicable to target 'expression'"

[image]

---

I have to revert to a different scope to get this to work:

[image]

---

**How can i fix my lint-rule in such a way, that i can target expressions?**

---

My current (simplified) implementation:

```
class MissingDefaultDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {

    companion object {
        private const val old = "Button"

        @JvmField
        val ISSUE: Issue = Issue.create(
            id = "PreferDefaultComposables",
            briefDescription = "Prefer 'DefaultComposables'",
            explanation = "The default implementation should be used",
            category = Category.CORRECTNESS,
            priority = 6,
            severity = Severity.WARNING,
            implementation = Implementation(
                MissingDefaultDetector::class.java,
                Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getApplicableMethodNames(): List<String> = listOf(old)

    override fun visitMethodCall(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression, method: PsiMethod) {
        context.report(
            issue = ISSUE,
            scope = node,
            location = context.getNameLocation(node),
            message = "Prefer our custom version(s) of this component",
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: May be if you declared the suppress lint inside composable scope which is not supported. Please check whether this is the case?

Comment: Could you please describe what i should do in more detail? I don't understand it, sorry.

Comment: I tried your code.I think we cant declare any annotation inside a composable function. If we declare the annotation or suppress lint outside is it not working?

Comment: Declaring the SuppressLint outside of the composable is working (see the third image). But i don't want to declare it outside of the composable - that's the whole point of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "This annotation is not applicable to target 'expression'" means that the @SuppressLint("PreferDefaultComposables") annotation cannot be used on an expression, only on a declaration (such as a class, field, method, or parameter).

In your code, the @SuppressLint("PreferDefaultComposables") annotation is being used on the Button function call. This is not allowed, because the function call is an expression, not a declaration.

To fix this there are two ways

**Approach 1 -**

```
@Composable
fun ButtonText() {

    // Declare the Button function call inside a lambda expression
    @SuppressLint("PreferDefaultComposables")
    val button: Unit = Button(onClick = { }) {
        Text(text = "Click me")
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
@Composable
fun ButtonText() {

    @SuppressLint("PreferDefaultComposables")
    @Composable
    fun InnerButton() {
        Button(onClick = { }) {
            Text(text = "Click me")
        }
    }

    InnerButton()
}
```

The default approach will declaring outside or onButtonText function. But your need is to declare inside. Hope these approach helps you

Comment: I would like to alter the lint check, not the way it's used

Comment: Can you please elaborate? If you alter anything please add here so that we can learn something

Comment: I just wanted to add a comment "It should behave like most of the compose checks, e.g. UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter". I checked and all compose lint checks i can remember do it in the way i wanted to avoid. Sooo i guess it's not possible

Comment: Granting the bounty anyhow since you invested lots of effort leading to my conclusion :)